# AngularJS http request doesn't send session cookie for CORS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors, session-cookies

My script is:

```
<script>
        function eventController($scope, $http) {  
            $http.get("http://example.com/api/Event", {withCredentials: true})
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.events = response;
                });
        }
</script>
```

Request header from Fiddler:

```
GET http://example.com/api/Event HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.example.com/Home/Event
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I need a authentication session cookie to be sent with this request.

It only sends cookie when the url of the webpage has no www in the front.

I have found a similar question in this site and the answer is:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //rest of route code
```

But where do I put this code in my script?

The web application I'm developing is an ASP.NET MVC5 app with Web Api 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my AngularJS script works fine (Just pass {withCredentials: true} as a parameter in the $http.get method). What went wrong was that my MVC application doesn't store session cookie in the subdomain. So I fixed it by adding CookieDomain in the CookieAuthenticationOptions.

Answer (score 0):

That configuration needs to be injected into the *angular module*, like this:

```
// get an existing module by name
var app = angular.module('app');

// inject $httpProvider configuration
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```